# how can I count every item in a list by a specific range? Also, why the last item in my output is not sorted?

Tags: python, list, sorting, count, range

I have written a code to receive the user input as a list.

```
def lst_data():
    lst = []
    total = int(input('Number of Data: '))
    for number in range(0, total):
        user_data = int(input('Enter the Data: '))
        lst.sort()
        lst.append(user_data)
    print(lst)
```

the output is:

```
[50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 68, 70, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 79, 79, 80, 80, 81, 82, 84, 86, 87, 88, 89, 89, 90, 91, 83]
```

The next step I want to do is count every item on that list by every 6 numbers like 50-55 = ???, 56-61 = ???, 62-67 =???, and so on.

I've been trying with:

```
counter =  0
for i in last:
    if 50 < i < 55:
    counter += 1

print(counter)
```

it works but I have to repeat the code over and over and value in the "if statement" has to be from the user input

how can i figure this out? and I want to check if there is any way to make my code simpler

Comment: Why are you sorting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are first sorting then adding the element, so in your loop sorting is done first and then the last element is added. Hence its left out. So you can swap the lines like below.

#### Your code

```py
def lst_data():
    lst = []
    total = int(input('Number of Data: '))
    for number in range(0, total):
        user_data = int(input('Enter the Data: '))
        # First append
        lst.append(user_data)
        # Then sort
        lst.sort()
    print(lst)
```

#### Suggested code

Below is the code with list comprehension.

1. loop interates over the `total` to take that many number of `inputs`
2. The values are then `added` to the list.
3. The list is then `sorted` out and `printed`

```py
def lst_data():
    lst = []
    total = int(input('Number of Data: '))
    lst = sorted([int(input('Enter the Data: ')) for i in range(total)])
    print(lst)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def lst_data():
lst = []
total = int(input('Number of Data: '))
for number in range(0, total):
    user_data = int(input('Enter the Data: '))
    lst.append(user_data)
    lst.sort()
print(lst)
```

use this code

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're trying to do:

```
def count(lo, hi, _list):
    return sum(lo <= e <= hi for e in _list)

nd = int(input('Number of data items: '))
data = []

for _ in range(nd):
    datum = int(input('Enter datum: '))
    data.append(datum)

lo = int(input('Enter low range value: '))
hi = int(input('Enter high range value: '))

print(f'There are {count(lo, hi, data)} items in the range {lo}-{hi}')
```

**Example:**

```
Number of data items: 5
Enter datum: 2
Enter datum: 1
Enter datum: 3
Enter datum: 5
Enter datum: 6
Enter low range value: 1
Enter high range value: 5
There are 4 items in the range 1-5
```

**Note:**

There is no reason to sort the list